# Solution for file server migration to Azure cloud

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, azure, migration, file-sharing, azure-files

I have a file server(2008 R2) running on my on-prem environment. I have around 400 users in my environment. I want to migrate this server to the Azure cloud with all SMB permissions. At the same time, I want users to access it over the public internet.

> As an example, let's assume there is a user called "Jhon" who has full
>   control of a specific folder in the on-prem file server. Once the
>   server is migrated to the Azure cloud, Jhon should be access it over
>   the public internet without having any VPN connections. Moreover, Jhon
>   should have his previous SMB access.

**What is the best solution for this kind of scenario?**

Assume no prem is sync with azure ad and azure adds is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read about "Azure Files"?

This should tie nicely with your current Azure ADDS deployment.

- You could migrate your existing file shares to Azure Files using simple tools, which will preserve the NTFS permissions and folder structure: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-migration-overview
- You could use one of the two available authentication methods, on both scenarios you will need to use "Azure AD Connect" though: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-overview

There are some limitations though, beware of them before you decide on this solution: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-faq